# File sizes for Map Reduce Programming and QA Testing of the code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

1. What is the size of files(and no of records) generally fed to map reduce programs in real time production systems ?
2. How do we test the code say unit testing and QA testing? Is it with few records ?

Answer (score 2):

1. In my experience we used hadoop to process daily loads of at least 100GB (in terms of records around 1billion with over 1000 fields).
2. For unit testing MR programs you can use few records or MRUnit.